# How to prevent salesforce from auto- formatting phone numbers

Tags: number, format, phone

I am using a lightning component to display a phone number.

I am currently in France and i want all the phone numbers to follow local formatting, which is not the case when i use the lightning component (Phone numbers are properly displayed in salesforce user interface).

So instead of displaying : **0474391085**

i am getting : **(047) 439-1085**

He is the code i am using to display the phone number along with a bunch of other fields :

```
 some code here for aura iteration
<lightning:outputField fieldName="{!eachItem}" class="slds-hyphenate" />
 some code here
```

I think that the **lightning:outputField** automatically recognizes the field as a phone and applies the standard **US** format.

Do you have an idea how to preserve the origin format ?

Comment: Did yoi try to use <ui:outputText ?

Comment: No, i t does not work, because in my code, "eachItem" contains the actual fields (fieldName__c) and the lightning:outputField uses this to fetch the data. when i use <ui:outputText> it actually prints out the field names

Comment: the notation is different -> {!v.myText}
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:outputText/example

Comment: @m Peixoto: I am using the variable in the context of an aura iteration so , i must use {!eachItem} instead of {!v.eachItem}